# C++ Singleton Instance disable re-call

Tags: c++, c++11, static, singleton

When using the Meyers singleton:

```
class Singleton
{
public:
    static Singleton& instance()
    {
        static Singleton instance;
        return instance;
    }

    void Hello()
    {
        std::cout <<"Hello!\n";
    }

protected:
    Singleton() = default;
    ~Singleton() {};

private:
    Singleton(Singleton const&);
    Singleton& operator=( Singleton const& );
};
```

You are able to call the instance as follow:

```
Singleton::instance().Hello();
```

or

```
Singleton& s = Singleton::instance();
s.Hello();
```

But I'm wondering if there is a way to block this:

```
Singleton::instance().instance();
```

How to avoid to call instance() as a method (with the `.`) and only support the static call with the `::` ?

Is there a way to use static_assert, template enable_if or anything else?

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to disallow it? Just curious

Comment: You can outsource the lifetime management into a `SingletonHolder` (possibly a class template). This way, `SingletonHolder<MyType>::instance()` returns an object that doesn't have an `instance()` method. Have a look at chapter 6 of "Modern C++ Design", which elaborates on this wrapper technique.

Comment: Let the Meyer's singleton die already...

Comment: @Rakete1111 No there is not. I only want to disable it because its misleading to call the instance over an other. So I would prefer a compile time error with static_assert if possible. I dont want to go with a huge work-around for a simple thing, I can live with it if nothing possible. Just wanted to see possibilities, because I couldn't found it myself.

Comment: @Vuwox THis is not a workaround, Meyers' Singleton is flawned at many levels. The use of Singleton is questionable, Meyers' is an error.

Comment: @Vuwox It all depends on your needs. Sometimes, a global variable is far less trouble than a singleton, you know. Think `std::cout` ;)

Comment: @Vuwox I'm fine with singletons in general. I just consider Meyer's singleton to be a rather poorly designed approach. Too often I see people giving up control over object lifetime and then complaining "singletons are bad for testing" and so on.

Comment: @YSC - Think possible static initialization order fiasco. Unless one takes extra measures ([like `std::cout` does](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/Init)).

Comment: @StoryTeller Yon can control the way your global variables (preferably stateless) are initialized, using singleton tricks namely :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, I don't think this is a practical concern. Nobody is going to write `Singleton::instance().instance().instance().Hello()`. Or rather, if people are writing that on purpose, I think you have bigger problems. This is fine, as-is.

---

If you really want to prevent that, then you just have to move `instance()` outside of the class so it ceases to be a member function. There's nothing for you to assert or constrain, since you cannot tell if your static member function was called on an object or not (and you cannot overload a static member function with a non-static one taking the same argument list). Either you can write both `Singleton::instance()` and `Singleton::instance().instance()`, or neither.

Simplest is just:

```
class Singleton {
    // ... 
    friend Singleton& make_singleton();
};

Singleton& make_singleton() {
    static Singleton instance;
    return instance;
}
```

Now it's just `make_singleton().Hello()`, and there's no other way to write that at all. This can be arbitrarily generalized by wrapping it in a singleton class template factory:

```
template <typename T>
struct SingletonFactory
    static T& instance() {
        static T instance;
        return instance;
    }
};

SingletonFactory<Singleton>::instance().Hello(); // ok
SingletonFactory<Singleton>::instance().instance().Hello(); // error
```

Comment: I went with the Factory. This can handle all the object (if more singleton is needed). The only thing we need to take care for this example, is that `Singleton` have a private ctor/dtor. So you need to add the `friend class SingletonFactory<Singleton>` inside the `class Singleton` to make sure to access the private elements. That way, I can ensure that my class Singleton is never created other than by using the `SingletonFactory`.